# Android - extract pixel color from screen

Tags: android, screen, pixel

I can't seem to find a good answer for this anywhere.

Is it possible to extract the a single pixel rgb directly from an android screen?  (Not by taking a screen dump)

I need direct access to what's on the screen.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly but I can give you an approach.
if the view's drawingCache enabled you can get bitmap from getDrawingCache and you can get pixel data from that.

Comment: Yes, thats something to look into, but I need to get the most upto date pixel color as I scan down the screen, so, getting a screen dump will be slow for my needs.

no direct access to pixel?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using custom views and canvases, you definitely can:

have a look:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixel(int,int)